# How to modify MVC routing to get more than one first-class urls

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have default routing set for my mvc application like:

```
   routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
```

I have Home controller with Index() and About(). Tell me please how to modify routing to get both domain.com/Index and domain.com/About urls?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this before your default route. By adding it before the default route, if it matches it will be used to set the RouteDictionary values. Untested, but it should map urls that only have a single component that is either `index` or `about`.  Note, that this assumes you don't have an index or about controller.  The routing constraint is important as it keeps it from matching on each controller's index action, e.g., `controller/`.

```
 routes.MapRoute(
       "IndexOrAbout",
       "{action}",
       new { controller = "home", action = "index", id = "" },
           new
           {
              action = "(index)|(about)"
           }
 );
```

Note, if you need to expand this to more top-level routes or make it more dynamic you could use a custom routing constraint that could draw the top-level values from a database or configuration.  At that point, you'd probably want to change it from using the action parameter to the id parameter and have a single action that use the id to determine what to show rather than have an action per value.